# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events, browser

For a few hours when I debug my application on my browser I have this error appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>   chrome-extension://fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej/scripts/optionsToggle.js

I open the link in a new tab in order to have the optionToggle.js code, wich is:

```
// Javascript for welcome page buttons
function showFirstTime() {
    $('#firstTimeSection').toggle('slow');
    $('#updatesSection').hide();
}
function showUpdate() {
    $('#updatesSection').toggle('slow');
    $('#firstTimeSection').hide();
}

document.getElementById('firstTimeBtn').addEventListener('click',showFirstTime);
document.getElementById('oldTimerBtn').addEventListener('click',showUpdate);
```

The line where the error occured is the penultimate line:

```
document.getElementById('firstTimeBtn').addEventListener('click',showFirstTime);
```

The only thing I made today is to update the chrome version.

Someone know what this error really means and how to solve her?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What is this a content Script or browser action/page action?

Comment: @Edwin It's not a content script of my web application that I am developped for the moment, I don't know where this script come from. It's the script the browser console give me, where the erro occured.

Comment: Well it's an extension you have an extension that is running that script. go to chrome:extensions in your browser, turn on developer mode and match the id: fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej

Comment: @Edwin, you have the good answer. It's the Hacker Vision extension who gave me this error. Make an answer for my question to explain your comment, in order to put this issue as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's an extension, you have an extension that is running that script. Go to chrome:extensions in your browser, turn on developer mode and match the id: fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej

Answer (score 0):

The real error here is that you are trying to add an event listener to a DOM object that doesn't exist on the page, which is why the error states you can't set that property on null.

Comment: yep thats probably it. use DOMContentLoad or .ready on .onload event

Comment: @Arm1stice, thank you for your answer, but Edwin gave me the solution to solve this problem. And it was the Hacker vision extension, since my last chrome update, who occured this error.